# In tensorflow NMIST beginner tutorial, how to actually use the results

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the next tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html

The problem is that I have not found any information on how to actually use this piece of code. The normal thing a newbie in the area want to do is to test some results to see what it is actually doing.

For example how to create an image and make a prediction, or how to save the trained model to a file.

Answer (score 2):

you could have a look at the tensorflow examples here: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples (https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/4_Utils/save_restore_model.ipynb)

It involves how to save the trained model and re-using it.

From the notebook:

```
# 'Saver' op to save and restore all the variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()
model_path = "/tmp/model.ckpt"
save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path)
```

Comment: that is very useful, I'll take a look and get back here